# Unable able to understand what the problem is while computing this statistical test

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributes, tuples

```
ljung_box_results = sm.stats.acorr_ljungbox(arima_fit1.resid)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 6))
sns.scatterplot(x=range(len(ljung_box_results)), y=ljung_box_results.iloc [:, 1], ax=ax)
ax.axhline(0.05, ls='--', color='red')
ax.set(title=f"Ljung-Box test results (after modeling {ticker8} stock prices)", xlabel='Lags', ylabel='p-value')
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/1l/x64tmr_d4yg4qr9l0kcplqdm0000gn/T/ipykernel_17122/3984955723.py in <module>
      3 ljung_box_results = sm.stats.acorr_ljungbox(arima_fit1.resid)
      4 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 6))
----> 5 sns.scatterplot(x=range(len(ljung_box_results)), y=ljung_box_results.iloc [:, 1], ax=ax)
      6 ax.axhline(0.05, ls='--', color='red')
      7 ax.set(title=f"Ljung-Box test results (after modeling {ticker8} stock prices)", xlabel='Lags', ylabel='p-value')

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Comment: could you share more info about your error it's hard to think about an error without having no knowledge about data.

Comment: The function `sm.stats.acorr_ljungbox()` returns 2 quantities in a tuple: a test statistic and a p-value, as a tuple. That tuple does not have an `iloc` attribute, as the message says. I suspect your code should be doing `ljung_box_results, p_value = sm.stats.acorr_ljungbox(...etc...)`.